# Count Blank Cells In Row if Another Row is not Blank in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, spreadsheet

In excel Im trying to count Items not listed

An example of how I am trying to achieve this would be:

Item Name ---------- Listed Date

Example Item 1   -----    12/12/12

Example Item 2 -----

Item 2 has not yet been listed.  so when it's all said and done i would like to see how many items are not listed.

I have tried using the following formula to no avail.

=IF(A:A <> "",COUNTBLANK(B:B))

Is there any way I can get the count of items not yet listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(B:B)
```

If column B is actually full of formulas which return a "", this won't work as COUNTA will include the cells with formulas. In which case use:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-(COUNTA(B:B)-COUNTBLANK(B:B))
```

Comment: The first formula you presented worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [INDEX function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):
Type the following formula in a blank cell and press *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. Then fill the cells down.

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(B:B="",ROW(B:B),4^8),ROW(A1))&"")
```

[image]

Comment: This is displaying the item name, what I am after is the total count of empty boxes.  Your example is set up correctly, although the final output I am after would have (for example) C2 would say Total Unlisted and D2 would simply have the number 2 since in your sample there are 2 items without a listed date.